# Duda con algoritmo de Python

Tags: python, tablas

¡Hola Comunidad!

Estoy elaborando un algoritmo en python, el cual consulta a una API para obtener el valor del dolar "Oficial" y "Paralelo" y devuelve ese dato. Sucede que lo arme todo en base a la función "print", pero necesito ir registrando esos datos en una tabla. ¿Cómo lo puedo lograr?, soy un poco nuevo en Python. Les paso el algoritmo:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tabulate import tabulate

url = 'https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales'

now = datetime.now()
json = requests.get(URL).json()

print()
print(' dolar | compra | venta | fecha')
print('-----|--------|-------|-------')

for index, dolar in enumerate(('Oficial', 'Paralelo')):
    fecha = now
    compra = json[index]['casa']['compra'][:-1]
    venta = json[index]['casa']['venta'][:-1]
  

    print(f" {dolar} |  {compra} | {venta} | {fecha}")

print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es simple usamos un array que contenga diccionarios para almacenar la todos los datos:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tabulate import tabulate

url = 'https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales'

now = datetime.now()
json = requests.get(URL).json()
datos=[];#Creamos una lista vacía que llenaremos en el bucle.
print()
print(' dolar | compra | venta | fecha')
print('-----|--------|-------|-------')

for index, dolar in enumerate(('Oficial', 'Paralelo')):
    datos.append({ "dolar":dolar,
                 "fecha":now,
                 "compra":json[index]['casa']['compra'][:-1],
                 "venta": json[index]['casa']['venta'][:-1]
                });# Agregamos la información dentro de un diccionario.
    print(f" {datos[-1]['dolar']} |  {datos[-1]['compra']} | {datos[-1]['venta']} | {datos[-1]['fecha']}")

print()
```

Comment: ¡Hola Daniel! ¡Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta! Entiendo lo que aplicaste, pero me lanza un error. ¿Sabrás que puede ser? :/ 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-05ad1adb7b47> in <module>
     20                  "venta": json[index]['casa']['venta'][:-1]
     21                 });# Agregamos la información dentro de un diccionario.
---> 22     print(f" {datos['dolar']} |  {datos['compra']} | {datos['venta']} | {datos['fecha']}")
     23 
     24 print()

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: :) error mio. recuerda que es un array de diccionario dato[num]["fecha"]. listo

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias! ¡Ahora si funciono! XD !!!